# Static multidimensional array, dimensionality definition at compile time

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, compile-time

Is there any syntax through which I can define the dimensionality of a static array at compile time? Let's assume I have a tuple of size D, with values `d_0,...,d_{D-1}`. I would like to be able to create an array `T arr[d_0][d_1]...[d_{D-1}]`. Is there any way to achieve this at compile time? I am specifically asking about static array syntax, not about how to nest structs.

Here's a code snippet to clarify what I want to achieve:

```
template<typename T, template<typename, auto> typename Container, auto DimC, auto...Dim>
struct NestedContainer
{
    using type = Container<typename NestedContainer<T, Container, Dim...>::type, DimC>;
};

template<typename T, template<typename, auto> typename Container, auto Dim>
struct NestedContainer<T, Container, Dim>
{
    using type = Container<T, Dim>;
};

template<typename T, int D>
struct Arr
{
    T e[D];

    T& operator[](int i) { return e[i]; }
};

template<typename T, int D, int...Dim>
struct MultiArr
{
    using multi_arr = typename NestedContainer<T, Arr, Dim...>::type;
    multi_arr e[D];

    auto& operator[](int i) { return e[i]; }
};
```

Used like so:

```
MultiArr<float, 3, 3, 3> a;
a[2][2][2] = 3;
```

I am curious whether this is achievable through some form of syntax without nesting classes.

Comment: Are the values in the `tuple` known at compile time (is it `constexpr`)?

Comment: Also, would you accept a `std::array` in place of a raw array?

Comment: @NathanOliver No, I am specifically asking about a plain static array. The tuple is compile time.

Comment: seems like you are searching for some kind of macro to generate the dimension brackets. however I doubt there is a generic way of population brackets at compile time without explicitly hard coding every possible set of array dimensions

Comment: Are the extents going to come from an actual `std::tuple` object or are you going to type them in as a comma-separated list as in your `MultiArr<float, 3, 3, 3>` example?

Comment: @Brian Can be either, but any suggestions are fine. I just want `e` to actually be `T e[d_0][d_1]...[d_{D-1}]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can easily be done using template metaprogramming recursion. The only tricky thing is that you need to apply the extents in the correct order. Note that `int[x][y]` is (conceptually) `(int[y])[x]`.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename E, size_t... extents>
struct MultiArrHelper;

template <typename E>
struct MultiArrHelper<E> {
    using type = E;
};

template <typename E, size_t extent, size_t... extents>
struct MultiArrHelper<E, extent, extents...> {
    using type = typename MultiArrHelper<E, extents...>::type[extent];
};

template <typename E, size_t... extents>
using MultiArr = typename MultiArrHelper<E, extents...>::type;

int main() {
    MultiArr<int, 2, 2, 3> a;
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a), int[2][2][3]>::value);
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b89020318e78b90

Comment: It's the `type[extent]` that does the trick right? From what I can see this recurses and keeps adding brackets until it reaches the type and then attaches it. That's exactly what I wanted to achieve, I wasn't sure you could do this though. Thank you.

Comment: @lightxbulb Well, the trick is to apply the first extent at the very end; that's what this does. If we wanted to apply the first extent first (which would give the wrong answer) then the `[extent]` would be right after `E`, rather than at the end.

Comment: Wait, is it vice-versa then? As I read it, assuming that I call `MultiArr<int,e1,e2>`, then first we'll get to the bottom of the recursion, setting `type = int`, then `type = (int)[e2]`, and then `type = (int[e2])[e1]`? Isn't this in reverse in some sense, or am I misunderstanding it? Is `(int[e2])[e1]` actually equivalent to `int[e1][e2]`? (I've put parentheses just to emphasize the order of application.

Comment: @lightxbulb I already explained this. You need to do `(int[e2])[e1]` in order to get the desired result `int[e1][e2]`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I wasn't certain I had understood it properly, now I understand what you mean.